# Non-graphical linearity estimation

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002638/), I was looking for correlation ratio (η or η<sup>2</sup>) routines in R. I was surprised by the fact that no one uses η for linearity checking in the GLM procedures.

How can I check linearity of bivariate correlation? Solely with scatterplot?

There are several ways of doing this, one way is to compare linear and non-linear model R<sup>2</sup>, then to apply F test to seek for significant difference between them.

How can I check linearity, the "non-grafical" way?

Comment: A far more important question is _why_ are you doing this and why don't you want to use graphics?

Comment: I wanted to get some info about non-graphical procedures, just out of curiosity, but it doesn't mean that I don't want to use graphics... on the contrary, I always look at the data in order to get an impression about the underlying structure (this may sound a bit toady, but I use `GGobi`, `rggobi` and `ggplot2` for those purposes). So there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer is what exactly you have said (comparing a linear and a non-linear model). 
e.g.

```
model1<-lm(yv~xv)
model2<-lm(yv~xv+I(xv^2)) #Even if we restrict ourselves to the inclusion of a quadratic term, there are many curves we can describe, depending upon the signs of the linear and quadratic terms

anova(model1,model2)

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: yv ~ xv
Model 2: yv ~ xv + I(xv^2)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)  
1     16 91.057                             
2     15 68.143  1    22.915 5.0441 0.0402 *
```

The more complicated curved model is a significant improvement over the linear model (p=0.04) so, in that case, we accept that there is evidence of curvature in the data.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is this procedure the same as the Mandel test?

Answer (score 4):

The RESET (Regression Equation Specification Error Test) was designed for missing regressors, but it us often used in testing non-linearities. Can be found in the LMTEST package -- among many other useful tests. It's very similar to what you are already doing. Alternatively, you could devise a test on recursive residuals to exploit the fact that they may become all positive/negative when ordered by entering non-linear variable.

Comment: +1 applying it on my test data: `resettest(yv~xv , power=2, type="regressor")` gave `RESET = 5.0441, df1 = 1, df2 = 15, p-value = 0.0402`

Comment: There's also `ramsey` function in `LDdiag` package